# How can I create a varicap in ADS?

Tags: ads, varicap

I need to create a varying capacitor, so I'm trying to make a varicap in ADS. However, there are only diodes, and I don't know how to make a varicap. Can you point me to some resources or walk me through this? I'm also fairly new to ADS.

Thanks

Comment: Did you look at the [documentation](http://cp.literature.agilent.com/litweb/pdf/ads2008/ccnld/ads2008/Diode_Model_(PN-Junction_Diode_Model).html)? Particularly section 6, "Diode Capacitances"? Which part specifically don't you understand?

Comment: @ThePhoton Well I didn't see that section, but looking at it now I still don't understand. It just lists a bunch of formulas. How do I convert that regular diode to a varicap?

Comment: You adjust the parameters that go into the formulas that vary the capacitance in response to bias voltage. VJ and M look like likely candidates.